# Contacts's manifest explanation

Tags: android, android-manifest, contacts

I'm developing a custom contacts app. I read default Contacts app source from Github and I don't fully understand. 
1, As far as I know ContactsSearchActivity will be called if an intent has action equal

> com.android.contacts.action.FILTER_CONTACTS ([full manifest](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/froyo-release/AndroidManifest.xml))

```
  <!-- The contacts search/filter UI -->
    <activity android:name="ContactsListActivity$ContactsSearchActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ContactsSearchTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.FILTER_CONTACTS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" android:host="com.android.contacts" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But the ContactsSearchActivity has no code.

```
public class ContactsListActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener,
        View.OnClickListener, View.OnKeyListener, TextWatcher, TextView.OnEditorActionListener,
        OnFocusChangeListener, OnTouchListener {

        public static class ContactsSearchActivity extends ContactsListActivity {

    }
```

So i don't understand if ContactsSearchActivity is called.([Full source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/froyo-release/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java))

2, The second is about search interface. I know activity which has

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"
```

is the activity handle query and display result. And the one has android:name="android.app.default_searchable" is enabled search + point to search handle activity.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".ContactsListActivity" />
```

But again in Contacts's manifest, [SearchResultsActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/froyo-release/src/com/android/contacts/SearchResultsActivity.java) is empty class extended from ContactsListActivity.

```
<!-- The contacts search/filter UI -->
        <activity android:name="SearchResultsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/TallTitleBarTheme"
            android:label="@string/contactsList"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"
            />
        </activity>
```

and

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".ContactsListActivity" />
```

in application tag not activity tag ([link](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/froyo-release/AndroidManifest.xml#L430)). 
I want to understand these because i don't know how to display this  [image: custom search] instead of [image: this]

Thanks in advance and sorry for long question.

**Edit**: It's ok with part1. In part 2, I want to display a custom diaglog when press search button but now i can only archive result in second image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my code and achieve my custom search dialog.

Answer (score 1):

That means everything is handled by the codes in `ContactListActivity`.

Take a look at the `onCreate` method of that, it reads the incoming Intent to determine how to display the result. It's nothing too special, as many Android app is working in this way.

Comment: 1,So if ContactsSearchActivity is called and no override method, it'll execute the ContactsListActivity(For simple it just like startActivity(this, ContactListActivity.class))?   <br/>

   


 2, and what about `<meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".ContactsListActivity" />` 
I define a similar but the search diaglog not appear. If i change to activity has searchable, the dialog appear.

Comment: Please look at the documentation for search http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
 for 1. it is different as the `Intent` containing extra stuff for searching, but `startActivity` may not include such searching intent.

Comment: It's ok with part1. Can you explain why `<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".ContactsListActivity" />` point to ContactsListActivity while according to develop.android it's normal point to activiy which has searchable

Comment: what do you mean by "has searchable"?

Comment: The activity has `<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"
            />
` in manifest

Comment: no idea for this one, in nowhere I found (in documentation) the use of this outside activity. But what I guess is writing this outside Activity tag means it is the default for all activities in this manifest.